# How to avoid aggravating a sprain while training in MMA?

Tags: injury

I've got a mild pain and swelling in my right hand's palm that I believe is a sprain. How to avoid aggravating my injury while continuing the training?

Comment: Well I checked and there's a "injury" tag which suggests this type of question has its place here. If my question is off topic then why this one isn't? http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-i-practice-any-of-the-martial-arts-after-a-hernia-surgery?rq=1

Comment: Your question is too broad and too medically focused in its current state. As mentioned [here](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/285/70) we give training advice, not medical advice. For example your question would be better if it asked how to avoid aggravating that specific injury while training in your specific art. *Treatment* and *what-might-happen* are both off topic.

Comment: Good point about the tag.  The wiki is empty for it, so I [asked a question on meta](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/354/82) about what it should be used for.  Good catch! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question based on slugster's comment.

Comment: Like it or not, sometimes medicine and training intersect.  MA is, to a degree, an interdisciplinary study.  Just as martial artists can be clueless about how to advise someone on medical topics, persons with medical degrees are often wrong about what is safe in training.  I personally know people who have been told they should never train martial arts again because of a torn meniscus.  Not trying to grind an axe here, just trying to say this kind of question shouldn't be dismissed out of hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't continue the training. Stop.

Think about it: your body is injured and needs time to heal. If you don't give it time, it won't heal.

It is MUCH better to not train for a week than to have unhealed damage which, after a few years, becomes much worse.

Comment: I really wish people would follow that advice, myself included... ^_~

Comment: You can lead a passionate person to a bed, but you can't make 'em rest! :)

Answer (score 2):

First - the obvious stuff for sprains:

- regularly ice it
- do not use the joints you believe you have injured

The second part gets a little tricky, because it means you have to adapt a lot of what you're training.  It will, however, improve the speed of recovery and the final results.

Second, the more involved aspect for sprains:

After 3-4 days of initial healing, your body begins growing new tissue to repair the damage as best it can.  You can help that tissue remodel better by doing gentle, isometric movement with the joint in question after those initial days.

You hold the joint in place, using your hand, part of your body, furniture, or a wall and press against it - for the smallest joints - about the force of lifting a coin, for the largest joints, at most the force of scooting a kitten.

As pain decreases and your range of motion returns you can increase the force until you're up to full again.

Edited to add: of course, if you have long standing joint, ligament, or bone conditions, go see your doctor!  Sprains are much more complicated when stuff like that comes up.